# Moya - How enable sample data?

Tags: ios, swift, moya

I started learning [Moya](https://github.com/Moya/Moya)  of for Netwroking

It required during implementing `TargetType`

Is there is way to not provide sample data for every end point

And, I can't to find way how enable/disable sample data.

```
var sampleData: Data {
    switch self {
    case .zen:
        return "Half measures are as bad as nothing at all.".utf8Encoded
    case .showUser(let id):
        return "{\"id\": \(id), \"first_name\": \"Harry\", \"last_name\": \"Potter\"}".utf8Encoded
    case .createUser(let firstName, let lastName):
        return "{\"id\": 100, \"first_name\": \"\(firstName)\", \"last_name\": \"\(lastName)\"}".utf8Encoded
    case .updateUser(let id, let firstName, let lastName):
        return "{\"id\": \(id), \"first_name\": \"\(firstName)\", \"last_name\": \"\(lastName)\"}".utf8Encoded
    case .showAccounts:
        // Provided you have a file named accounts.json in your bundle.
        guard let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "accounts", withExtension: "json"),
            let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url) else {
                return Data()
        }
        return data
    }
}
```

How I can do it?

**Answer**

```
static let provider = MoyaProvider<VMAPI>.init(stubClosure: MoyaProvider<VMAPI>.immediatelyStub)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For disable or enable sample Data in Moya, we should init provider with required state.

```
static let provider = MoyaProvider<VMAPI>.init(stubClosure: MoyaProvider<VMAPI>.immediatelyStub)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this code for sampleData in moya**

```
var sampleData: Data {
        switch self {
        case .login(_,_):
            return "Half measures are as bad as nothing at all.".utf8Encoded

        default:
            return Data()
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

if you want to neglect Simple data

```
  var sampleData: Data {
           return "There is No smaple Data".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!
    }
```

or if you want to use simple data just do as you Do in your question

Comment: return Data() is enough for this case